# Bash: using greping string from variable while curl

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I am trying to use `grep` in a while loop that runs `curl`.

```
    i=1
    while read -a row
    do
      test $i -eq 1 && ((i=i+1)) && continue
      STRING=${row[2]}
      CURL=`curl ${row[0]}${row[1]} | ${grep '$STRING'}`
      echo $CURL
    done < <(echo "SELECT check_address, check_page, check_string FROM checks" | mysql monitor)
```

The problem is in the line `"${grep '$STRING'}`". Since `grep` needs to be `grep 'text'` I tried different ways like `grep '$var'`, `${grep $var}` couldn't make it work.

SQL Output:

```
    ${row[0]} = http://www.codeoasis.com/
    ${row[1]} = index.php
    ${row[2]} = Copyright
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to capture the output of `curl` or `grep`:

```
i=1
while read -a row
do
  test $i -eq 1 && ((i=i+1)) && continue
  STRING=${row[2]}
  curl ${row[0]}${row[1]} | grep "$STRING"
done < <(echo "SELECT check_address, check_page, check_string FROM checks" | mysql monitor)
```

Note the use of double-quotes around `$STRING`, rather than single quotes.

Comment: When i run it i still get empty response:        [root@oasis monitor]# ./Monitor.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22248    0 22248    0     0  75002      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2450k

Comment: Please add the output of your SQL query to your question. Right now, it appears that the URL is fine (2450k returned), but that the requested string just isn't present.

Comment: its present if i type the string now with in a variable it works , the only problem is with grep that wont read the variable ( i echo it and its there )

Comment: output of SQL:
${row[0]} = http://www.codeoasis.com/
${row[1]} = index.php
${row[2]} = Copyright

Comment: I Copied the code as your wrote it, unforunatly it still give me empty output [root@oasis monitor]# ./Monitor.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22248    0 22248    0     0  83854      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2450k
[root@oasis monitor]#